# Check the class of an object from Box2d's user data

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am trying to determine the type of object when detecting collision with Box2d. I want to be able to assign the user data to an object and check to see if its of the correct class type

```
id object = b->GerUserData():
```

Then

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[MyClassObject class]])
```

However i just get the error "Cannot initialize a variable of type'id' with an rvalue of type 'void*'

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to assign an object of type 'id' to a void * type

The method call  body->GetUserData(); returns a void pointer. Here it is as defined in the header file of b2Body.h

```
/// Get the user data pointer that was provided in the body definition.
void* GetUserData() const;
```

Now, if you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), you need to perform an additional step to cast it back.

```
 id object = (__bridge id) b->GetUserData();
```

If you are not using ARC, then...

```
 id object = (id) b->GetUserData();
```

As for checking the type, there are many ways to do this. I personally prefer having an enum called GameObjectType. I can then assign the type in the appropriate constructor of the object. Here is an example of how I do it in my games

```
 for (b2Body * b = world->GetBodyList(); b != NULL; b = b->GetNext()) {

    Box2DSprite * sprite = (__bridge Box2DSprite*) b->GetUserData();
    id obj = (__bridge id) b->GetUserData();


    if (sprite.gameObjectType == kGroundTypeStatic
        || sprite.gameObjectType == kWallType
        || sprite.gameObjectType == kGroundTypeDynamic) {

        // Insert Logic here
    } // end if

    sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
    sprite.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle() * -1);

} // end for
```

Here is how I would go about creating the sprite (Using ARC)

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO,
                      location.y/PTM_RATIO);

// Setting the enum value
self.gameObjectType = kTankType;
self->body = self->world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
self->body->SetUserData((__bridge void*) self); // Obtain sprite object later

GB2ShapeCache * shapeCache = [GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache];

[shapeCache addFixturesToBody:self->body forShapeName:@"Earth_Tank"];

self.anchorPoint = [shapeCache anchorPointForShape:@"Earth_Tank"];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, worked perfectly and a very informative answer

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your game

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the error is on this line:

```
id object = b->GetUserData();
```

That might be because the return type is void pointer. Try to cast it like that:

```
id object = (id)b->GetUserData();
```